# Tomcat - Click on Web Service gets "The requested resource is not available"

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, servlets

I am newbie for Java web services and tomcat.

I didn't find a specific answer, so I am trying...

I have built a war to deploy on a tomcat 8.0.28 server on windows (and later on Solaris)

On the "Tomcat Web Application Manager" I can see my webapp listed among the applications list and I see that it's "running" status is "true". (see image)
[image]

Doesn't it mean that the service is up and running?

I have two problems, which probably relate:

1. When I click on the application link on the Tomcat Web Application Manager, it gives me 404 error. Is it logical? Why is that?
2. On the WAR project I have a main method, in which I create a file. I can't find it, so I assume, it was never called. I guess it relates to the previous matter...

   My suspicion is that I didn't configure the address well somewhere. I will try to pass here all the data that I think is relevant:

   The **application path**, as it is shown in the "Tomcat Web Application Manager" is /CcgwServerWsCxf.

   The **display name** as it is shown in the "Tomcat Web Application Manager" is CcgwCallbackWsServerWAR.

   The servlet part in web.xml is as follows:

> ```
> <servlet>
>   <servlet-name>CcgwCallbackServlet</servlet-name>
>   <servlet-class>com.mycomp.ta.load.CcgwCallbackServlet</servlet-class>
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>   <servlet-name>CcgwCallbackServlet</servlet-name>
>   <url-pattern>/CCGWCallback/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

This is my code in the port **server** class constructor:

```
    System.out.println("Starting Server");
    Object implementor = new CCGWCallbackPortTypeImpl();
    String address = "http://192.168.5.106:1234/CCGWCallback/CallbackServer";
    Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);
```

(1234 is my tomcat port)

The service address that I send to the **client** so it can send my notification messages back is:

```
http://192.168.5.106:1234/CCGWCallback/CallbackServer
```

The Serivce QName is

```
new QName("http://teleconference.mycompany.com/CCGW", "CCGWService");
```

I hope that I gave all the data.

Can you please help?

Thank you.

Comment: in your web.xml it should read `url-pattern` and not `url-pmycompern`

Comment: 1) *When I click on the application link on the Tomcat Web Application Manager, it gives me 404 error. Is it logical?* if there isn't any kind of welcome page, sure. 2) *On the WAR project I have a main method, in which I create a file.* what does that mean, "a main method" ? If it is a public static void main, those are irrelevant in web applications

Comment: @Gimby Regarding 2, yes - that makes sense, stupid me... So, does it say that once I start the tomcat service, the App port type server class is automatically loaded? I talk about the class that was generated by Apache CXF: CCGWCallbackPortType_CCGWCallbackSOAPPort_Server

Comment: @wero it is a url-pattern. Some kind of typo mistake. I will fix it ... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context path of your application is `/CcgwServerWsCxf` and your servlet is mapped to `/CCGWCallback/*` (relative to the context path).

Any request with path below `/CcgwServerWsCx` is routed to your application.
But only requests with a path below `/CcgwServerWsCx/CCGWCallback` hit your servlet.

Therefore Tomcat responds with a 404 when you call `/CcgwServerWsCxf` (e.g. the hyperlink in the manager app).

You should call `/CcgwServerWsCx/CCGWCallback` and verify that your servlet is invoked.

Also you need to make sure that any client also uses the correct paths. For instance the URL `http://192.168.5.106:1234/CCGWCallback/CallbackServer` should probably be `http://192.168.5.106:1234/CcgwServerWsCx/CCGWCallback/CallbackServer` given your current Tomcat config.